# How do I only enable re-ordering for UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a bunch of UITableViewCell's in my UITableViewController. When I set editing to YES, it automatically enables deletion of each cell. How do I disable the delete feature? I only want to let the user reorder the cells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:
        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

It controls whether a minus, a plus or nothings shows up

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I want.

Comment: That's the way.  I forgot it's not a property of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Set the cells' editingStyle to UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone and -showsReorderControl to YES.  In your -tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
[myCell setShowsReorderControl:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you, although I don't think setEditingStyle worked. I had to implement - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: You're right, that's the correct way to set it.  Did that work then?